# geth process is stopped because debug_traceBlockByNumber

Tags: geth

geth version:
[Version: 1.9.24-stable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkNJF.png)

When I send the request, the geth process stops.

```json
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "debug_traceBlockByNumber",
    "params": [
        "0x242c60",
        {"tracer": "evmdisTracer"}
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

geth error logs:
[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOpni.png)

how should i solve this problem?

Comment: Please, do not post text data in image format. Copy your version info and log data and paste it as plain text in code block (that begins and ends with three backticks ``` ). You could check [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about asking.

Comment: I'm running geth light node on same geth version, but I'm having very hard time to find peers. Do you have the same issue?